# redirect to a route using post method

Tags: php, laravel

i've registered a post route and set the "auth" middleware on it,everything is working properly but at the last step when i want to redirect to my registered route after authentication,an error occurred, it seems redirect() helper function uses GET method by default,but my route supports POST method.is there any way to use redirect() with POST method?!!

```
Route::post('match', 'HomeController@match')->name('match')->middleware('auth');
```

and inside my LoginController:

```
if ($is_match==='comes_from_match') {                   
    return redirect()->route('match');
}else{
    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
}
```

this leads to the following error:
"The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."

Comment: Why using post method? is there's any header data you need to send?

Comment: Browsers support only GET request while redirecting to a new URL unless it's a form POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

You can use `any` instead of `post` it works for both `get` and `post`.

```
Route::any('match', 'HomeController@match')->name('match')->middleware('auth');
```

Answer (score 0):

As per latest `Laravel` documentation:

> Sometimes you may need to register a route that responds to multiple HTTP verbs. You may do so using the `match` method. Or, you may even register a route that responds to all HTTP verbs using the `any` method:

You can use `match` or `any` method:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', function () {
    //
});

Route::any('/', function () {
    //
});
```

Reference:

[Laravel -> Routing -> Basic Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#basic-routing)